# I have a dropdown menu but my menu won't dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i have a question about my dropdown menu, it won't drop down and i have searched here on the stackoverflow (which helped me a lot with other things) but i can't find the problem that i have

this is my html code: p.s. i use  in the html code

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="radio.html">Radio</a></li>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="web.html">Webradio</a></li>
            <li><a href="win.html">Winacties</a></li>

        </ul>

    <li><a href="playlist.html">Playlists</a></li>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="vandaag.html">Playslist van vandaag</a></li>
            <li><a href="win.html">Playlist van de week</a></li>

        </ul>

    <li><a href="nummer.html">Welk nummer was dat?</a></li>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="welke.html">Nummers van vandaag</a></li>

        </ul>
    <li><a href="over.html">Over ons</a></li>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="wie.html">Wie zijn wij</a></li>

        </ul>
</ul>
```

and this is my css code:

```
nav ul ul{ display: none; }

nav ul li:hover> ul {display: block; }

nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table; }

nav ul:after {content: ""; clear: both; display: block; }

nav ul li {float: left; }

nav ul li:hover {background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%); }

nav ul li:hover a {color: #fff; }

nav ul li a {display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none; }

nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%; }

nav ul ul li {float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative; }

nav ul ul li a {padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff; }  

nav ul ul li a:hover{background: #4b545f; }

nav ul ul ul { position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0; }
```

so what's wrong with my code? do i need to change something? is my code just wrong? what is it???

please help me, because i really need it
it would really help if u guys will help me out :)

Comment: Your css selectors are referring to `<nav>`… i don't see a nav in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your html, this:

```
<li><a href="radio.html">Radio</a></li>

<ul>

    <li><a href="web.html">Webradio</a></li>
    <li><a href="win.html">Winacties</a></li>

</ul>
```

Should be:

```
<li><a href="radio.html">Radio</a>

    <ul>

        <li><a href="web.html">Webradio</a></li>
        <li><a href="win.html">Winacties</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

Notice how the first `li` is closed on the last line?

Then you can show the sub-menu with:

```
li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

Comment: thank you very much jonas, sorry for the simple error i'm feeling kinda stupid now

Answer (score 3):

You're closing the parent `li` tags for the top level menu items, before including the submenu `ul`, change your HTML thus:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/9LBWL/1/)

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="radio.html">Radio</a>    
            <--! closing li should NOT be here -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="web.html">Webradio</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="win.html">Winacties</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li> <--! closing li should be here -->
        <li><a href="playlist.html">Playlists</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="vandaag.html">Playslist van vandaag</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="win.html">Playlist van de week</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="nummer.html">Welk nummer was dat?</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="welke.html">Nummers van vandaag</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="over.html">Over ons</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="wie.html">Wie zijn wij</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

As you have it, you are using invalid HTML, nothing should appear outside `li` children within `ul`.